# can't get soapUI into PHP function

Tags: php, web, soap, service, wsdl

I have been struggling for hours now on a SOAP connection and can't get it to work, this is what I have:

```
$url  = 'https://xxx/connector.svc?singleWsdl';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'pass';

$options = array(
        'uri'=>'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
        'style'=>SOAP_RPC,
        'use'=>SOAP_ENCODED,
        'soap_version'=>SOAP_1,
        'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'connection_timeout'=>15,
        'trace'=>true,
        'encoding'=>'UTF-8',
        'exceptions'=>true,
    );
try {
    $soapclient = new SoapClient($url, $options);
#   $soapclient = new SoapClient($url);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

I tried '?wdsl' but then I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: <message> 'IConnector_GetProduct_ServiceFaultFault_FaultMessage' already defined
```

A request with no parameters works fine:

```
$result = $soapclient->GetVersionInfo();
$last_request  = $soapclient->__getLastRequest();
$last_response = $soapclient->__getLastResponse();
print "Request:  ".$last_request ."\n";
print "Response: ".$last_response."\n";
print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Request:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="Unit4.AgressoWholesale.Connectors"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetVersionInfo/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Response: <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><GetVersionInfoResponse xmlns="Unit4.AgressoWholesale.Connectors"><GetVersionInfoResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Unit4.AgressoWholesale.Common.Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><a:FullVersion>14.4.18.0</a:FullVersion><a:Release>14</a:Release><a:ServicePack>4</a:ServicePack><a:Fix>18</a:Fix><a:Version>0</a:Version><a:CustomCode/><a:AWBuild>38</a:AWBuild><a:AWFix>003</a:AWFix><a:AWCustomBuild/><a:AWCustomFix/><a:AWCustomCustomerCode/></GetVersionInfoResult></GetVersionInfoResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
stdClass Object
(
    [GetVersionInfoResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [FullVersion] => 14.4.18.0
            [Release] => 14
            [ServicePack] => 4
            [Fix] => 18
            [Version] => 0
            [CustomCode] =>
            [AWBuild] => 38
            [AWFix] => 003
            [AWCustomBuild] =>
            [AWCustomFix] =>
            [AWCustomCustomerCode] =>
        )

)
```

So far so good, but the trouble begins trying to log in, which is a must.. In SoapUI it works with:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:unit="Unit4.AgressoWholesale.Connectors" xmlns:unit1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Unit4.AgressoWholesale.Common.Contracts">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <unit:Login>
         <unit:SecurityContext>
            <unit1:SessionToken></unit1:SessionToken>
            <unit1:UserId>user</unit1:UserId>
            <unit1:Password>pass</unit1:Password>
         </unit:SecurityContext>
      </unit:Login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But converting this to PHP, I'm stranding here..  this is what I have tried:

```
$data = array( 'SecurityContext' => array( 'SessionToken' => ''
                                        ,'Password'     => $user
                                        ,'UserId'       => $pass)
                            );
$data = array( 'SessionToken' => ''
                            ,'Password'     => $user
                            ,'UserId'       => $pass
                            );

$data = new stdClass;
$data->SecurityContext = new stdClass;
$data->SecurityContext->SessionToken = '';
$data->SecurityContext->UserId       = $pass;
$data->SecurityContext->Password     = $user;

#$result = $soapclient->__call('Login',array($data));
#$result = $soapclient->Login($data);
$result = $soapclient->__soapCall('Login',array($data));
```

But no matter what I try, event without parameters or an empty array or stdClass, I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [s:ServiceFault] An exception occurred
```

It's driving me nuts, I can't find anything on the internet about the fatal exeption '[s:ServiceFault]'

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, writing out the problem sometimes is enough to get to an anwer!

The solution was two-fold:

1) get better error reporting by using a try{} catch:

```
try { 
    $result = $soapclient->__call('Login',array($data));
    #$result = $soapclient->Login($data);
    #$result = $soapclient->__soapCall('Login',array($data));
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    $error = $e->faultcode;
    echo str_replace('>',">\n",$error) ;
}
$last_request = $soapclient->__getLastRequest();
$last_response= $soapclient->__getLastResponse();
print "\nRequest: " .str_replace('>',">\n",$last_request);
print "\nResponse: ".str_replace('>',">\n",$last_response);
```

That way I got just that litle more information I needed! to:

2) enter password in the password field and the username in the user field

It works!

For those interested

- Using the array structure and the 'new stdClass' both work
- all three ways of parsing the call work (also the two commented out ones, use which one you like)